# Getting OS name and version from Linx os-release file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm attempting to get the OS name (pretty_name)and version (version_ID) on one line via the /etc/os-release file, in a simple command.

Currently, I have the following:

```
cat /etc/*-release | egrep "PRETTY_NAME|VERSION_ID" | cut -d = -f 2 | tr -d '"'
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
7.9
Red Hat Enterprise Linux
```

I'm looking to get my output looking like this:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.9
```

What can I do to get the output the way I want it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**; the order of the contents of `/etc/*-release` can't be guaranteed. This answer focus on OP's case;

---

Use [`tac`](https://linuxhint.com/bash_tac_command/) to reverse the output, then use `tr '\n' ' '` to concatenate the lines;

```
cat /etc/*-release | egrep "PRETTY_NAME|VERSION_ID" | cut -d = -f 2 | tr -d '"' | tac | tr '\n' ' '
# 10 Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
```

---

Another option would be to read the second and third line of `lsb_release` witch has a more consistent output;

```
lsb_release -as 2>/dev/null | sed -n 2,3p | tac | tr '\n' ' '
# 10 Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
```

Comment: Is the order of output guaranteed to remain constant? Granted, the shell will sort glob results in the current locale, but if one host has a file named `centos-release` and the other has `ubuntu-release`, whether they sort before or after `lsb-release` is going to be different.

Comment: Yea, don't think the order is guaranteed to be this way, either way, OP is asking for the `/etc/os-release` file.

Comment: ...and whether your OS vendor puts `PRETTY_NAME` or `VERSION_ID` first within the same file isn't defined or guaranteed to remain the same at all.

Comment: Why not hardcode `/etc/os-release` instead of using `cat` with a glob, then? Also a little faster if you give grep a direct file handle (or a name so it can create such a handle itself) instead of forcing it to read from a FIFO.

Comment: Granted, order can't be guaranteed, but that's a reason that I'd be looking for an answer to be order-independent before giving it an upvote.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, just something that built upon what I already had. Once again a new command I had no idea that it existed.  Then with the `lsb-release`, this isn't an option for minimal RHEL install.

Answer (score 3):

Since `os-release` is in shell format (and provided by your OS vendor, whom you're obliged to trust), you can just source it (which treats the quotes as syntax rather than data, so they don't need to be manually removed).

Amending to follow the [advice from @Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361502/getting-os-name-and-version-from-linx-os-release-file/65361662#comment115554548_65361662) to prefer Red Hat's extended metadata over the generic variable names when available (but falling back to the generic names otherwise):

```
. /etc/os-release
printf '%s %s\n' \
  "${REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT:-$PRETTY_NAME}" \
  "${REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION:-$VERSION_ID}"
```

Comment: I suggest: `echo "$REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT $REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION"`